# PHP Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, paypal

I am connecting my site to PayPal [using this excellent guide](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php).

I've done this before without any problems, however I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context
```

It appears to be caused by this line of code:

```
if(!empty(_SESSION('ppl_products'))&&!empty(_SESSION('ppl_charges'))){
```

What does this error mean? I didn't get it when I connected the paypal API on seperate hosting.  Is it a server issue?

Comment: `_SESSION`? Maybe `$_SESSION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty()` is a language construct.  It consumes a variable name.  As such, you can not write to it.  The return of a function writes out to a variable.

Your best bet is to ommit the `empty` and just check the truthiness of the return:

`if(_SESSION('ppl_products') && _SESSION('ppl_charges')){`

Then again, if `_SESSION` is not a function, and you are attempting to access the global session variable, then you are doing it a few kinds of wrong, and you must do it like this:

`if(!empty($_SESSION['ppl_products'])&&!empty($_SESSION['ppl_charges'])){`

Comment: Changing $_SESSION( ) to $_SESSION [ ] worked perfectly! Thanks.  I'll accept when the timer allows.

Answer (score 0):

This error looks familiar to me, because I had the same Problem when using a function return value with `isset` (As in: `isset(myFunction())`). Because, as [kunststube.net points out](http://kunststube.net/isset/), you can't do that with `empty` or `isset`.

While I don't see an obvious function call here (maybe there's one happening offstage?), you could try substituting the `!empty($something)` for `$something == true`, which is equivalent, but might give you more hints as to where the error lies.